# Wordpress URL direct to another root directory

Tags: php, wordpress, web-applications

Good day friends, I would like to ask for assistance on configuring Wordpress.

I would like to create a link where the user can access my web application using the url provided below.

For example.

***mydomain.com*** - Wordpress

***mydomain.com/application/*** - Web application

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You may have to specify the page name for your application especially if you do not have an index.html/php or default.html/php.

Comment: I have index.php, I just need how can i force wordpress reading the index of a specific directory.

Comment: You might need to explain what you want a little better. As it stands, I can't quite understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

just put application folder inside your wordpress web application folder with wp-admin , wp-content etc

Comment: you application have any index file , please try to hit url like this 
mydomain.com/application/index.html